# Map A Dictionary With Pandas Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe column `province` which contains `USA states and Canada province` names in both uppercase and lowercase

`df.province`

Output

```
MANITOBA
Alberta
CA
OH
```

A dictionary to map all Canada province values

```
ca_provinces_dic = {
    'Newfoundland and Labrador': 'NL',
    'Prince Edward Island': 'PE',
    'Nova Scotia': 'NS',
    'New Brunswick': 'NB',
    'Quebec': 'QC',
    'Ontario': 'ON',
    'Manitoba': 'MB',
    'Saskatchewan': 'SK',
    'Alberta': 'AB',
    'British Columbia': 'BC',
    'Yukon': 'YT',
    'Northwest Territories': 'NT',
    'Nunavut': 'NU',
}
```

How to map all the `province` values with their respective short form using pandas that handles the `case matching` issue as well?

For example -
I want to compare all the `province column values` (in lowercase) with all the `dictionary keys` (in lowercase) and based on the match I will apply the appropriate short form for the province column values (only where applicable)

---

My current attempt to this problem.

```
canada_provinces_dic = {
    'Newfoundland and Labrador': 'NL',
    'Prince Edward Island': 'PE',
    'Nova Scotia': 'NS',
    'New Brunswick': 'NB',
    'Quebec': 'QC',
    'Ontario': 'ON',
    'Manitoba': 'MB',
    'Saskatchewan': 'SK',
    'Alberta': 'AB',
    'British Columbia': 'BC',
    'Yukon': 'YT',
    'Northwest Territories': 'NT',
    'Nunavut': 'NU',
}


def handle_state(data_attr):
  for k, v in canada_provinces_dic.items():
      if data_attr.strip().lower() == k.lower():
        return canada_provinces_dic[k]
  else:
    return data_attr
```

```
df['state'] =  df.state.apply(handle_state)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

First convert your dict to keys in lowercase:

```
In [638]: ca_provinces_dic = {k.lower():v for k,v in ca_provinces_dic.items()}

In [659]: df['province'] = df['province'].str.lower().map(ca_province_dict).fillna(df['province'])

In [660]: df
Out[660]: 
  province
0       MB
1       AB
2       CA
3       OH
```

Comment: Working great, thanks!